# How much time has passed in the Walking Dead From Book 1 to 94?

Tags: comics, the-walking-dead

I have read that from the start of infection to the time Rick wakes up, was about a month or two.

How much time has passed from Rick's awakening to issue 94? It is more than one year?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long has it been since the initial outbreak?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7024/how-long-has-it-been-since-the-initial-outbreak)

Comment: Is the show caught up to the comics though? That question seems to go to season 2 of the tv show.

Comment: @Beofett, no this is not duplicate because that is about the TV episodes, and this about the book :) Maybe it is more difficult than that... Let's see if appear a answer :)

Comment: Fair point about comic vs. tv.  I've created a [meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1702/are-questions-duplicate-if-they-share-a-topic-and-a-title-but-not-a-medium) to clarify my concerns, and find out what community consensus is. I apologize for the close vote, as I would rather take it back until I see how the meta discussion goes. When I cast it, I did not catch the emphasis on the comics, but I can't "unvote" it.

Comment: @Beofett don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have my issues of *The Walking Dead* handy, but around issue No. 90 or so, the editors explicitly state that fifteen months have passed since the initial outbreak.  I believe it was the issue right before the comment from Rick about how canned fish should not be good for three years.